# Вывести массив в виде массива

Tags: php, массивы, функции, callback

Столкнулся с такой задачей

Сallback (анонимные) функции
Для всех заданий:

- использовать array_filter или array_map;
- на входе для всех заданий, дан массив:

```php
[

    ['name' => 'Yan', 'salery' => '1200', 'work_hours' => 180],

    ['name' => 'Barda', 'salery' => '2150', 'work_hours' => 160],

    ['name' => 'Piter', 'salery' => '1500', 'work_hours' => 160],

    ['name' => 'Alex', 'salery' => '3340', 'work_hours' => 167],

    ['name' => 'Deiv', 'salery' => '1700', 'work_hours' => 176],

    ['name' => 'Bob', 'salery' => '1150', 'work_hours' => 182],

    ['name' => 'Claus', 'salery' => '2810', 'work_hours' => 155],

    ['name' => 'Lina', 'salery' => '1600', 'work_hours' => 169],

    ['name' => 'Rod', 'salery' => '2780', 'work_hours' => 191],

    ['name' => 'Kristy', 'salery' => '2180', 'work_hours' => 144],

    ['name' => 'Ron', 'salery' => '1670', 'work_hours' => 157],

]
```

- выводить результирующий массив в табличном виде для каждого задания.

Задание:
Всем сотрудникам у кого ЗП меньше 1600 добавить 100.

Я сделал так:

```php
<?php

$arr = [['name' => 'Yan', 'salery' => '1200', 'work_hours' => 180],
    ['name' => 'Barda', 'salery' => '2150', 'work_hours' => 160],
    ['name' => 'Piter', 'salery' => '1500', 'work_hours' => 160],
    ['name' => 'Alex', 'salery' => '3340', 'work_hours' => 167],
    ['name' => 'Deiv', 'salery' => '1700', 'work_hours' => 176],
    ['name' => 'Bob', 'salery' => '1150', 'work_hours' => 182],
    ['name' => 'Claus', 'salery' => '2810', 'work_hours' => 155],
    ['name' => 'Lina', 'salery' => '1600', 'work_hours' => 169],
    ['name' => 'Rod', 'salery' => '2780', 'work_hours' => 191],
    ['name' => 'Kristy', 'salery' => '2180', 'work_hours' => 144],
    ['name' => 'Ron', 'salery' => '1670', 'work_hours' => 157],
];


// задача 1
function salery($n)
{
    if ($n['salery'] < 1600) {
        return $n['salery'] + 100;
    }
    return $n;
}

$b = array_map('salery', $arr);
print_r($b);
```

Вроде все ок, все выводит
Но не понимаю как этот массив сделать таблицей ((

Помогите плиз

Comment: анонимные функции, это когда у функции имени нет. а если вы явно пишите имя `function salery()` (причем с ошибкой в английском слове), то это обычная именованная, очевидно, функция, а не анонимная.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php $arr(Ваш массив); 
        $chery=count($arr); 
        for($i = 0; $i <= $chery-1; $i++) { 
        echo'<table cellspacing="0" border="2" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 200px">'; 
    echo'<tr>'; 
echo '<td style="width: 200px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap">'.serialize($arr[$i]['date_of_monitoring']).
        '<td style="width: 200px;">'.serialize($arr[$i]['name']).
        '<td style="width: 200px;">'.serialize($arr[$i]['salery']).
        '<td style="width: 200px;">'.serialize($arr[$i]['work_hours']).'</td>';
         echo'</tr>';
         echo'</table>'; 
        } 
        ?>
```